# How to use OracleConnection with different queries C#

Tags: c#, oracle, odac

I can't understand how to work with OracleConnection object

Use it for all queries? Or one connection for one query?

My program do:

1) Recieve data from Oracle DB (cursor) (~100.000 - 1.000.000 records)

2) For each selected record (id) update value at another table

What is correct:

1) Create OracleConnection for each query

```
using(OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))  
{
    using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(recieveSql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        ...
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ...
        using(OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string value = reader.GetInt32(1);
                UpdateRecord(id, value);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void UpdateRecord(int id, string value)
{
    using(OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))  
    {
        using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(updateSql, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            ...
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

2) Use 1 OracleConnection for all queries

```
using(OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))  
{
    using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(recieveSql, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        ...
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ...
        using(OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string value = reader.GetInt32(1);
                UpdateRecord(connection, id, value);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void UpdateRecord(OracleConnection connection, int id, string value)
{
    using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(updateSql, connection))
    {
        ...
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say there's an obvious overhead opening 100.000+ connections for all those updates. But if you did not simplify your task/code for the sake of this question, I'd argue why writing any C# code at all? A simple UPDATE from one DB to another could be done directly in SQL.

Comment: Because I want to have a opportunity to change value or do something with it from program before save to DB
Mostly I just want to learn C# - Oracle communication and my program don't do something useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I would prefer the 2nd one, only 1 database connection.

Keep in mind that opening a `OracleConnection` is expensive both on the client side and also on the dataserver side.

Often, the guideline is 1 thread => 1 `OracleConnection`.

If you have multiple threads or you're still want to use multiple `OracleConnection`, you can define a `OracleConnection` pool just setting some parameters in the connection string.